# Implementing one hot encoding

Tags: neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I already understand the uses and concept behind one hot encoding with neural networks. My question is just how to implement the concept.

Let's say, for example, I have a neural network that takes in up to 10 letters (not case sensitive) and uses one hot encoding. Each input will be a 26 dimensional vector of some kind for each spot. In order to code this, do I act as if I have 260 inputs with each one displaying only a 1 or 0, or is there some other standard way to implement these 26 dimensional vectors?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to differ between various frameworks. I can speak for [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), which is my goto framework when programming a neural network.

There, one-hot encodings for sequences are generally performed in a way where your network will expect a sequence of *indices*. Taking your 10 letters as an example, this could be the sequence of `["a", "b", "c" , ...]`
The [embedding layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Embedding) will be initialized with a "dictionary length", i.e. the number of distinct elements (`num_embeddings`) your network can receive - in your case 26. Additionally, you can specify `embedding_dim`, i.e. the output dimension of *a single character*. This is already past the step of one-hot encodings, since you generally only need them to know which value to associate with that item.

Then, you would feed a coded version of the above string to the layer, which could be looking like this:  `[0,1,2,3, ...]`. Assuming the sequence is of length 10, his will produce an output of `[10,embedding_dim]`, i.e. a 2-dimensional Tensor.

To summarize, PyTorch essentially allows you to skip this rather tedious step of encoding it as a one-hot encoding. This is mainly due to the fact that your vocabulary can in some  instances be quite large: Consider for example Machine Translation Systems, in which you could have 10,000+ words in your vocabulary. Instead of storing every single word as a 10,000-dimensional vector, using a single index is more convenient.

If that should not completely answer your question (since I am essentially telling you how it is generally preferred): Instead of making a 260-dimensional vector, you would again use a `[10,26]` Tensor, in which each line represents a different letter.

Comment: A 10x26 tensor (aka matrix) still has 260 elements, so the answer to the OPs question is: yes, your network will have 260 inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 distinct elements(Ex: a,b....j OR 1,2...10) to be represented as 'one hot-encoding' vector of dimension-26 then, your inputs are 10 vectors only each of which is to be represented by 26-dim vector. Do this:

```py
y = torch.eye(26)      # If you want a tensor for each 'letter' of length 26.
y[torch.arange(0,10)]  #This line gives you 10 one hot-encoding vector each of dimension 26.
```

Hope this helps a bit.